# Python: How to use multiple list with a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to use each item in a printed list to store in a database. So each item will called separately to store it a table (this table has two columns, column ip address and column port).
I have two list: list_a where all ip addresses(e.g. 192.168.1.143) are stored and list_b (e.g. 22) where all port numbers are stored.

```
result_list = []
for host in list_a:
  for port in list_b:
    result_list.append([host,port])
      for item in result_list:
        print item
```

With this code I get following output, which is correct:

```
['192.168.1.143', 22]
['192.168.1.51', 22]
['192.168.1.50', 80]
['192.168.1.43', 22]
['192.168.1.61', 20]
['192.168.1.60', 80]
```

But when I access items in the list with item, item[0] or item[1], only the last elements are stored. In this case  ['192.168.1.60', 80].
How can I store all of the element in a list, so I can use all the elements in a list?

Comment: Can you make this a [mcve]? As it is, it's hard to figure out what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Also, the indentation of your code looks incorrect. And there's a syntax error on the 3rd line: your missing an `in`. If you can't make an MCVE we at least _need_ to see samples of what `list_a()` and `list_b()` do; just showing us the output of your code is insufficient.

Comment: I've edited the question , is this sufficient?

Comment: Why are you iterating through result_list for every iteration of the inner loop?

Comment: @Phebe: You still have an indentation error. And I suspect you don't want the `for item in result_list:` loop to be inside the other loops. And you still haven't shown us `list_a` and `list_b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem was that the script generated multiple lists(as shown above). The solution was to print the output in a nested list,like this:

```
[['192.168.1.143', 22],['192.168.1.51', 22],['192.168.1.50', 80],['192.168.1.43', 22],['192.168.1.60', 80]]
```

From here I created another for-loop to access all the elements.Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but if you want the Cartesian product of the two lists, I think this is the pythonic way:

```
from itertools import product
for p in in product(list_a,list_b):
    do_stuff(p)
```

edited slightly in accordance with Copperfield's tip.

Comment: why make a list just to unpack it? product accept any number of arguments...

Comment: Aha, I did not know that. I'll edit and credit you.